# How we change the rangeSelector in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there any way we can change the `rangeSelector` from date and to date on click any button.

I want to provide two buttons so user can move the selection forward and backward.

Visit [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x0Lnp977/1/) regularly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [`setExtremes`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.setExtremes) method. First you need to get your current minimum time on the xAxis using [`getExtremes`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.getExtremes). Next you set your new maximum time to the minimum time. I used [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to handle subtracting months (or whatever your range selection is). I find out what range button is selected and then use the `value` and `type` to determine how much of what type of date to subtract to get my new start time. I have only done this with the `3m` setting you have in your demo. You will need to add the logic for any other type. You will also have to handle going backwards too much such that you are now out of the data range - this can be done but I leave it up to you.

Basic "back" button function:

```
$("#btnBack").click(function() {
    var theChart = $('#container').highcharts(),
        extremes = theChart.xAxis[0].getExtremes(),
        minTime = extremes.min,
        maxTime = extremes.max,
        currRangeIndex = theChart.rangeSelector.selected,
        currRange = theChart.rangeSelector.buttonOptions[currRangeIndex],
        newMaxTime = minTime;

    // new start/end times
    var startTime,
        endTime;

    if (currRange.type == 'month') {
        var endDate = new Date(newMaxTime);
        var startDate = moment(endDate);    
        startDate.subtract(currRange.count, 'months');

        startTime = startDate.valueOf();
        endTime = newMaxTime;
    }   
    theChart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(startTime, endTime);
});
```

Working "back" button [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x0Lnp977/2/).

Comment: Also, custom buttons can be rendered via http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.button http://jsfiddle.net/x0Lnp977/3/, so range selectors functionality can be altered in a more custom way.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I was need.

Comment: Forward is not working. Is there I am doing something wrong

Comment: Forward is not working. Is there I am doing something wrong.     http://jsfiddle.net/x0Lnp977/7/